# Are too low/changing voltages damaging (to Arcade PCBs)?

Tags: voltage, 5v, damage

This is about Arcade PCBs (like a Neo Geo MVS or Sega Naomi) and it might actually be two questions.

An arcade power supply (JAMMA compatible) supplies +5V, +12V and -5V. The +5V line can be dialed up and down a little and for some PCBs it has to be set up right or they won't run at all.

Should I use a "+5V" voltage that is **just high enough** to get my device to run or should I try to get as **close** to the specification (if available) as I can? As an example, for a Sega Naomi you will find statements like "use exactly +5.0V" or "just don't go higher than 5.1/5.2V", but I found it might run at 4.85V as well.

And, as I have to measure voltage while the device is running (correct?), is it better to change the voltage **while the device is running** or to switch the device **on and off** between changing voltages? I heard arguments against both options, but as far as I know you have to choose one. I am more worried about long term damage, than about comfort. This is about the PCB not the user.

On a related note, there is this notion going around that a device might "get used to" some specific voltage. Is there any truth to that?

Comment: As usual in these circumstances follow what the datasheet says. For your other assertions, do you have any links to information rather than what seems like dubious opinion?

Comment: As for the questions of adjusting the voltage running vs on-off-cycles and "getting used to voltage": nothing, just opinions. That's part of my problem!

Comment: In my experience, performing a live voltage adjustment on operating equipment is really only a good idea if a technical manual says that you can. And I can't think of a mechanism that would make a board behave better at the same voltage over time, other than the voltage itself drifting into an acceptable number. And it WILL drift, eventually. I would argue that, when in doubt, a nominal 5 volt rail producing exactly 5 volts stands the smallest statistical chance of creating a problem. Also, lower voltages create excess heat through increased current - through passive components, anyway.

Comment: So, would you, Sean, say that multiple times of switching the whole system on and off are a better idea (than live voltage adjustment)? I didn't know about the drift, I will check voltages from time to time and readjust.

Comment: @Higemaru, please use the "@" sign when directing comments, as Stack Exchange will notify the receiver - just take out spaces. Any reasonable power supply is capable of being cycled some rather large number of times, and is probably less likely to destroy boards than live adjustment. Note that this is not a hard and fast rule! As far as checking and adjusting periodically,  it's not a bad idea, but don't beat yourself up with it. You probably don't need to check and adjust more than annually, or when there's a problem. "If it ain't broke, don't fix it" is a valid maintenence plan for most.

Comment: @SeanBoddy (seems to be correct, auto-completion agreed!) thank you, I am new to Stack Exchange, I didn't know it's this "smart". Okay, that's one of the questions I had, leaning more towards your answer, but I am not an expert at all, so thank you. I noted you said the **power supply** will withstand many cycles. Will cycles put more strain on the power supply than on the game mainboards components? That would actually be good news as the power supply is much more easily replaced/repaired than some exotic processors.

Comment: The big deal is usually inrush currents into storage capacitors. Proper power supplies can limit it or deal with it. The processors start up sequence shouldn't cause it too much stress, compared to operating under load. Remember that these are generalities from my experience; you may find a credible technical authority that says to do it live. But for myself, if I trusted the supply's ability to load regulate, I would energize it out of the machine, adjust it, lock the rheostat, plug it in and test. Repeat as necessary. This avoids sending haphazard voltages to the processor.

Answer (score 1):

Your +5v doesn't need to be spot on, but it should be within a reasonable tolerance.  If your chips are spec'ed at 4.5 to 5.5v (which is common for logic series like the 74HCTxx family) then I would try to keep the 5v supply within ±5%, or 4.75 to 5.25v so you are comfortably within the chip limits.  Using this criteria, your voltage of 4.85v would be acceptable.

In general, I think it is a little better to be under-voltage than over-voltage, as the latter may put more stress on parts.

As far as adjusting the voltage while the circuit is turned on or not, I am going to suggest a slightly different approach.  Assuming you are making the adjustment using a potentiometer of some sort, using a screwdriver, if you turn the power supply off to make the adjustment, turn the pot a ways, and then turn the power supply back on you won't know for sure the voltage will still be within safe limits when it is back on.  So that is a bad idea.

If you can, it would be better to disconnect the PCB from the power supply.  Then you can adjust the voltage while leaving the power supply on, watching the voltage change with a multimeter.  Once you have the voltage adjusted the way you want, hook the PCB back up to the power supply (with it off of course), turn it back on and measure the voltage again. Your power supply should be well-regulated, but it is still possible for it to droop a bit under the full load of the system.  In that case, you can make teeny adjustments the supply to bring it into spec.

Comment: I think the problem with your approach is that there is quite a big difference in voltage on these devices. So having 5V on the power supply will probably result in some games not booting at all. Measurements I made showed 5.22 V at the power supply and 4.97 V at the connector that goes into the Naomi mainboard. (There is a so called IO board between them.) So are you saying that adjusting the dial just a little bit (only dialing up, say, 0.5 Volts) is unlikely to cause damage?

Comment: I'm saying you should first disconnect your power supply from the PCB, and then adjust it for 5v.  Turn the PS off, connect it to the board, turn on the PS and measure it again.   If it is, say a quarter volt too low now, turn off the supply, disconnect it again and this time adjust your PS up by a quarter volt.  Plug it into the board and measure it a second time.  You should not be much over 5v, if at all.  At least that is what I would do.

Comment: I understood your procedure, it's just that I had a character limit, so I had to delete some sentences which made my comment less clear, sorry. I am guessing that what you said means that the voltage that's "lost" on the way from the PS to the PCB is more or less a constant factor, or that there is a roughly linear relation between the two voltage levels. Thank you.

Comment: @Higemaru, this is pretty much what we were discussing in comments under the original question, and the one you should probably go with. Personally, I never liked the odds that my fingers slip and I overtweak the rheostat. Also, consider that lower voltages make more heat in passive components, but higher voltages make more heat in active devices like processors. +1 for tcrosley.

Comment: @SeanBoddy -- Sorry if I stole your idea.  Your comment was hidden (under the "show 2 more comments" line) and I apparently forgot to click on that.

Comment: @tcrosley, no worries friend. I didn't even file an actual answer on this one since all I had was generalities. Still got my vote.

Comment: @SeanBoddy I still think there is different (non contradicting) information coming from you and tcrosley. Both of which helped, so thank you both!

Comment: @tcrosley Sadly I can't upvote anything, I lack reputation, but let me say thank you.

Answer (score 0):

On your arcade PCB there are a bunch of ICs and a bunch of passive components like resistors and capacitors.

Among your ICs, you would have standard and specialized logic.  If you could find datasheets for these chips, you could discover their specific "recommended operating conditions".  For example, [the NXP 74HCT14](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT14.pdf) has a recommended operating voltage of 4.5V to 5.5V (5V +- 10%).  Operating it outside these voltages may cause it to not meet the functional requirements; operating it above the "limiting values" may damage the IC.  For ICs that are nominally 5V, a typical tolerance is +-10%.  In googling, I found some claims that Jamma's tolerance is +-5% (or 4.75V-5.25V), but none of these was particularly authoritative.

Capacitors are also sensitive to voltage.  A capacitor is rated to a specific voltage (e.g., 6.3V is a typical capacitor rating in a nominal 5V circuit), and applying a higher voltage can damage the capacitor. Capacitors also tend to lose capacity as they age—sometimes catastrophically, as in [capacitor plague](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor_plague).

As capacitors are used to "smooth" voltage over varying loads, the result can be that the whole board works erratically or stops working when a capacitor is bad.  It's also slightly possible that running such a board at a higher voltage will make it appear to work reliably again.  Inspect your board for "tented" or otherwise damaged caps, and replace any you find.

Other than the scenario where a board with dodgy capacitors might function unreliably, I am not aware of any sort of "memory" that would cause a board to "work better" at a specific voltage just because it was operated at that voltage in the past.

Comment: Thanks to you and other commenters, I think I have a better picture of how to handle these PCBs now. It's good to hear that some of the "advice" I found is most likely bogus.